# Hand written script image processing with android

Tags: android

I am working on a project with android SDK. The idea is that we write with hand on a paper 3+3 and make its image. the android phone scan that image and after recognizing the values and symbols provide us with answer 6. Is there any free api available for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the process into steps. It will surely be easier to find APIs for each individual action:

1. Obtain image from the camera (Android API is enough)
2. Image processing: Thresholding (binarization), rotating (Image Processing libraries, maybe [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/)).
3. Segmentation: Obtaining individual characters as a binary array.
4. Character recognition - recognizing characters one by one (many approaches - maybe neural networks).
5. Adding numbers - easy one!

Answer (score 0):

check http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/. This provides OCR functionality for smartphones but not sure if it will work for handwriting stuff. Also check [this](http://devforum.visionobjects.com/) and [this](http://www.visionobjects.com/en/media-and-community/news/bdd/actualite/60/titre/vision-objects-announces-first-cloud-based-handwriting-recognition-service-for-developers-october). This might help you